# Asp.Net NoCaptcha not updating in UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net

NoCaptcha image works fine if i don't add UpdatePanel, but if i add UpdatePanel it does not update on postback. Here is my code :

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelTriggers" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>

            --NoCaptcha
            <div id="captcha" runat="server" class="login_re_captcha_hidden">
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="Key">
                </div>
            </div>

        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnLogin" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="uprCampaigns" runat="server" DisplayAfter="0" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanelTriggers">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div class="loadingIconBackground">
                <div style="height: 85px; top: 0px; width: 100%">
                </div>
                <div style="min-height: 100%; background-color: White">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="loadingIconDiv">
                <img src="images/PleaseWait_Small.gif" />
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Here is my server side code. I use this code to validate the user's answer :

```
private bool ValidateUserReCaptchaResponse()
        {
            bool validated = true;

            if (Request["g-recaptcha-response"] != null && Request["g-recaptcha-response"] != "")
            {
                string sCatchaResponse = Request["g-recaptcha-response"];
                string sSecret = "key"; //put in webconfig
                string sIPAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString();
                sIPAddress = "x.2x.x.18";

                // Next create a WebClient instance to call the web api and get the result... 
                System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
                string sRequest = String.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}&remoteip={2}", sSecret, sCatchaResponse, sIPAddress);
                string sResponse = wc.DownloadString(sRequest);

                //add  <system.net>
                //<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
                //</system.net> for DownloadString(sRequest) in webconfig

                // The result comes back as a JSON object. I've created a simple GoogleResponse object to hold this information 
                // and am using the JavaScriptSerializer to deserialize the response accordingly... 
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                GoogleResponse response = serializer.Deserialize<GoogleResponse>(sResponse);

                // Now we can just check if the call succeeded or failed and take the necessary action 
                if (!response.success)
                {
                    // just output an error on the front end here 
                    validated = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // ok if you're here, you basically didn't check that bot question on the form. 
                // Tell the user to do so and resubmit the form
                validated = false;
            }

            return validated;
        }
```

Please help ?

Comment: How does the version look like where you say the captcha works but UpdatePanel is missing?

Comment: What do you mean by version ? I basically mean nocaptcha does not work with UpdatePanel. I needed UpdatePanel in order for me to show a loading icon. Here is the nocaptcha link :  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>

Comment: You write: "NoCaptcha image works fine if i don't add UpdatePanel", so I had the impression you had a version of your code that somehow did "work fine" in some way (feel free to elaborate) and that could help figure out the problem.

Comment: Yes i was trying to show that the problem is with the Update panel. So nocatcha works fine without AjaxToolKit controls(UpdatePanel). So now i would like it to work with AjaxToolKit controls(UpdatePanel).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean it's not working in a PostBack when you click btnLogin right?
Because that's the only trigger you defined. Maybe try setting the EventName.

It should at least work when you do this:

```
UpdateMode="Always".
```

**Update:**
Now I think I understand what happens. If I am correct you have also included a javascript file that calls the render method which defaults to unload. So if I am correct the UpdatePanel updates and still needs you to call:

```
grecaptcha.render();
```

or specify the arguments. Can really see whether they are mandatory or not. By default it should look for the first tag it finds and use the attributes set, so wouldn't expect the parameters to be mandatory.
See documentation https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param

Either you disable calling the render/onload on initial load, so you can always do:

```
$(function() {
        grecaptcha.render();
}
```

Or you add the mechanism to call client side code for updates with UpdatePanel.
Explanation can be found on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398976(v=vs.140).aspx

An example that should work (but I am typing this by head on a MacBook, so can't verify/test it) is adding this to the markup of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PartialPostBackFinished(sender, args) {
         //Do whatever also needs to be triggered, esp when you want it to be applied on panels_updated only to avoid registering events multiple times

         grecaptcha.render()
    }

    if (Sys != undefined) {
        //There's a ScriptManager on the page
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(PartialPostBackFinished);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes. I tried Always mode but no luck. The nocaptcha image gets displayed only once on IsPostBack=false.

Comment: Do you have code-behind for the control with id captcha?

Comment: Yes the code to validate the user's answer. I tried to paste it here, but i get an error message that says my characters are too long.

Comment: Maybe add an update to your post. Comments have a lower maximum length.

Comment: I can email you my project so that you can have a look if it's okay with you ?

Comment: Well, that won't help others if they have the same issue. Just update your initial question with the code that does something with captcha and where it's running.

Comment: I have added the server side code. Please check my initial question ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80482/discussion-between-dacker-and-chosenone-thabs).